# Java: Printing trailing spaces

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm a beginner in Java and working on a code that first requires user to enter total number of integers and next the integers themselves. Example input is:

```
4
1 4 3 2
```

The code will need to reverse the second input to the following:

```
2 3 4 1
```

My solution is as follow:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    int arr[] = new int[n];
    for(int arr_i=0; arr_i < n; arr_i++){
        arr[arr_i] = in.nextInt();
    }
    for(int reverse_i=n-1; reverse_i>=0; reverse_i--){
        System.out.print(arr[reverse_i]);
            if(reverse_i != 0){System.out.print(" ");}
    }
}
```

My question is related to the code to add a blank space " " in between the printed numbers. I wonder what other way I can use to get this done? Any suggestion is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The way you have tried works fine i suppose sorry i didnt see that @ first

Comment: May I know why my question is downvoted please?

Comment: lol I became your senior with 2 downvotes. I should't have answered

Comment: I get nervous every time I post something here. The fear of losing points is so real! LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way to reverse a string is using the `StringBuilder` class:

One option is to remove the spaces at the end of the string eg. remove last char

```
package stackoverflow.main;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(int arr_i = 0; arr_i < n; arr_i++){
            sb.append(in.nextInt());
            sb.append(" ");
        }

        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);

        String normal = sb.toString();
        String reversed = sb.reverse().toString();

        System.out.println("normal: " + normal);
        System.out.println("reversed: " + reversed);
    }
}
```

Another option is to check whether you are at the last `arr_i` of your loop.
If so, then don't add a space

```
package stackoverflow.main;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(int arr_i = 0; arr_i < n; arr_i++){
            sb.append(in.nextInt());
            if (arr_i != 3
                sb.append(" ");
        }

        String normal = sb.toString();
        String reversed = sb.reverse().toString();

        System.out.println("normal: " + normal);
        System.out.println("reversed: " + reversed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

First reverse the array and then print it with a for loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int arr[] = new int[n];
        for(int arr_i=0; arr_i < n; arr_i++)
        {
            arr[arr_i] = in.nextInt();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length / 2; i++)
        {
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[arr.length - i - 1];
            arr[arr.length - i - 1] = temp;
        }    
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The same as what you did, only to consider the last element shall be printed out of the 'for' loop.
(*a quick and easy solution*)

By this way, you reduce the time with the validation of each iteration and you do know that the last element is the one without the 'space'.

I wish to be useful for the software development community.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    int arr[] = new int[n];
    for(int arr_i=0; arr_i < n; arr_i++){
        arr[arr_i] = in.nextInt();
    }
    for(int reverse_i=n-1; reverse_i>0; reverse_i--){
        System.out.print(arr[reverse_i]+" ");
    }
    System.out.print(arr[0]);
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

It is all about output formatting. You may use [this examples](https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples) and become familiar with all possible approaches.

Your code can be improved in next two ways :

1) Use `\t` instead of Empty Space (`\t` is a tabulation)

2) Create a constant with output format like this `private static final String output = "%d "` and use it in output line like this : `String.format(output, number)` where `number` is your number that should be printed.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer but I think it could be because \t will have more than a single " " when used?

Comment: `\t` is a just representation of `TAB` from ASCII table. It will cost 1 character.